# Google Cloud HTTP Balancer and gzip

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

When i was using Google Cloud Network Load Balancer all my HTTP gzip connections where left intact, but when using HTTP/S Load Balancer end users don't get the gzipped content.

I'm using nginx on the VM. Using this curl example:

`curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "Host: my.website.com" -I https://$IP_TO_TEST/login --insecure`

I get `Content-Encoding: gzip` when connecting direct to the VM and no gzip when I connect to the HTTP load balancer.

I've searched all the Google cloud documentation for this and they don't mention whether they support or don't gzipped content from backends.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Google Cloud HTTP/S load balancer supports gzipped content from backends.  However, requests proxied through the load balancer will have a ['Via: google 1.1'](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#components) header added.  The default nginx configuration [does not trust proxies to be able to handle gzipped responses](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/compression-and-decompression/).  The solution is to enable [`gzip_proxied`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_proxied).

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP/S load balancer supports gzipped content from backends.  Do you have an example of request and response headers you could share?  What are you running on the VM (nginx, Apache)?

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'm using nginx on th VM. Using this curl example curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "Host: my.website.com" -I https://$IP_TO_TEST/login --insecure I get _Content-Encoding: gzip_ when connecting direct to the VM and no gzip when I connect to the HTTP load balancer

Comment: It's the Via header.  Let me write up a full answer.